# How to use AutoAction->True with LocatorPane with more than one Locator?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to have a LocatorPane with more than one Locator using LocatorAutoCreate option.

But I'd also like to set AutoAction->True, so that when the mouse is over a locator, it moves automatically with the mouse. i.e. works like dragging.

I am basically trying to just have the dragging feature of LocatorPane, and do not want the clicking feature of LocatorPane, as it complicate something else I am doing.

i.e. I just want to be able to just drag points across a locator pane. Clicking on the locatorPane should do nothing. One way to do that I found is by setting AutoAction->True. Is there a better way to disable Clicking effect on LocatorPane?

The problem is that, when I have more than one locator, Mathematica kernel crashes right away.

So, I am asking if there is a way to use AutoAction->True with LocatorPane with more LocatorAutoCreator at the same time. Or if there is a way to just allow dragging, and clicking should do nothing.

Here is an example

```
LocatorPane[{{0,0},{.4,.5}},
Graphics[{Gray,Disk[]}],
AutoAction->True,
LocatorAutoCreate->{1,5}]
```

### Make sure you save your work before running the above, as it will crash Mathematica once the mouse is over the Pane.

Version 8.0.1, Windows 7.

**Update:**

FYI; I got a reply from WRI tech support on this today. The problem has been reproduced and send to Mathematica development team to investigate.

Comment: Crashes on version 7.0.1 / Windows also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try:

```
LocatorPane[{{0, 0}, {.4, .5}, {.1, .1}}, 
             Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}], 
             AutoAction -> True, LocatorAutoCreate -> {All}]
```

Comment: +1, That nice trick did it. It is strange that Kernel would crash though. I just did send a bug report to WRI. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser Remember to update your question if you receive feedback from WRI!